# Unable to increase API quotas after upgrading account to paid

Tags: google-api

We updated our API account from free to paid, but it is not letting us increase the quota. My understanding is there should be an option if I go to 
APIs & auth --> APIs --> select API --> Quota,  but there is not.

Can anyone assist?

[image: Cannot increase quotas]

[image: Account has been upgraded and billing enabled]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to extend the quota on all of the Google APIs unfortunately  Geocoding API is one of the APIs that you can't extend the quota on.

From the documentation [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

> Usage Limits
>
> The Google Geocoding API has the following limits in place:
>
> **Users of the free API:** 
>      * 2500 requests per 24 hour period.
>      * 5 requests per second. 
>   **Google Maps API for Work customers:** 
>      *100 000 requests per 24 hour period. 
>      * 10 requests per second.

## update:

New pricing changes went into effect on July 16, 2018. For more information, check out the [Guide for Existing Users](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/)

please note that while billing can now be enabled so of the quote limits ate still not going to be extendable.  these being mainly the flood protection quota's

Comment: Hi, thanks. So why do they say in the Dev Console to activate the billing to extend the quota?

Comment: Probably because it's a standard screen and it's part of the maps api I will ping someone at Google see if we can get a note on the page or in the documentation.    Thought they had fixed it already

Comment: We are having the same problem, and Geocoding API DOES now support pay-as-you-go, per the docs linked above. This answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 0):

so  in OVERVIEW there is option Explore this API. click on that it will redirect you to the API console page. there you can change the limit for your api.

Comment: Hi, The explore option makes a normal request to calculate a distance, nothing more.

Comment: sorry my mistake its not Explore this API its View reports in API Console. it will take you to console.

Comment: I have no option "Request more" in front of Distance Matrix API